# Horizontal scrolling with buttons in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to add a scroll view horizontally. It should contain several buttons. And every time when Itouch a button it should scrolled to the center. just like this

[image]

When ever I touch a button it should scroll to this arrow location. how can I do that?

Please help me

Comment: set `contentoffset of scrollView` at the time of button Action

Answer (score 0):

You should set your scrollers content offset x value to your button mid position plus your screen width:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
       UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
       float offsetPointX = button.frame.origin.x - button.frame.size.width/2 + [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width;
       yourScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offsetPointX, yourScrollView.contentOffset.y); 
 }
```